# TreeView, give value

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have this code:

```
foreach (MyClass info in data)
    {
    if (info.year!= "" && info.year!= null)
    {
        TreeViewYear.SelectedNode = TreeViewYear.RootNodes[0].Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Content?.ToString() == info.year);
    }
}
```

Imagining that the foreach runs twice with the years "5" and "2", he selects correctly but then when he runs the second time, gets only the 2 value, that is, the value 2 and withdraws the 5.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can't understand your question very well. Please be more specific about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select more than one item, you should set the `SelectionMode` of the `TreeView` to `Multiple` and add the items to be selected to the `SelectedNodes` property:

```
TreeViewYear.SelectedNodes.Add(
    TreeViewYear.RootNodes[0].Children.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Content?.ToString() == info.year));
```